# Does a statement 'this.xxx' in an object also declare a property named xxx?

Tags: javascript, object, declaration

The code below is what I got in my sample html file.

```
function Blog(body, date) {
    // Assign the properties
    this.body = body;
    this.date = date;
}
```

There's no declaration statement, I see. I think it's supposed to have something like this before those two statements: `var body; var date;`

Or do those two statements work like declaration statements too?

Comment: If my memory is still working you need to do `var body; var date;`

Comment: In Javascript's object-orientation, object properties can be populated via assignment statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly with your code:

```
var puppies = new Blog(samplebody, 'some/date/here');

console.log(puppies.date);

//prints out some/date/here to the console
```

This is because "puppies" has already been declared as an object. Any variable declared inside the "function" as `this.key = value;` is essentially just adding a key value pair to the object.

You can skip specifically defining variables that are assigned to a defined javascript object.

Think of it as defining new elements in a dictionary object. Once the dictionary is defined you can then add elements to it without individually defining those elements:

```
var person = {};
person.name = 'Murphy';
person.favoriteBook = 'The Hungarian Caterpillar';
```

Comment: Then can I skip `var key;` at all times?

Comment: Added a another example to answer if you can skip specifically defining variables in objects.

Comment: Did this answer your question?